# Can an ORDS FilterObject be case insensitive?

Tags: oracle-ords

Is there a way to add a JSON FilterObject to an ORDS query that would be case insensitive so that:

```
https://example.com/ords/scott/emp/?q={"ENAME":{"$like":"JOHN%"}}
```

Would match, "JOHN", "John", etc.  I can do this in the supporting SQL but I'd rather let the users create their own filters rather than baking it in behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

No but I'll add it to our future ER list.